# How can I get Perl's debugger and gVim to work together on Linux?

Tags: perl, debugging, vim

Is there a way to get Perl's debugger and gVim to work together on Linux?  I.e. step through code in gVim and see the values of watched variables controlling the debugger from within gVim?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this vim script: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=663 for debug perl scripts in your vim editor.

Answer (score 2):

This is a decent plugin with some debugger integration: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556.

Comment: Does this play well with things like OmniComplete and SuperTab?